# Php not displaying a simple object variable

Tags: php

I have this object :

```
var_dump ($filtres) ;
```

**Result:**

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'filtres' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'table' => string 'crm_comptes' (length=11)
```

I'm simply trying to echo it, it doesn't work :

```
echo $filtres->table;
```

It stays BLANK, I've tried plenty of things, like converting it to an array, all of that, it still doesn't want to display `'crm_comptes'`

I've tried this :

```
echo $filtres['table'];
```

It still displays nothing.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: From the output, it looks like you need `$filtres->filtres->table`

Comment: Thank you, yes it is working now !

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen you output result, it seems your result `$filtres` is an `object of an object for table`. You should get it as:

```
$filtres = $filtres->filtres;
echo $filtres->table;
```